# Скрытие кода в PyCharm по определённому пресету

Tags: python, pycharm

Решился я ту значится заняться систематизацией своего кода (ake. Свои правила пометки непонятного решил сделать). И возник вопрос может ли PyCharm сворачивать код по пресету. См. Пример

```
# <object_start>
object_x, object_y = 12, 15
object_width, object_height = 25, 10
object = Human
object.setName('John')
object.setIq(1000-7)
# <object_end>
```

Как вы поняли он должен сворачивать код между комментами ,а пресет сворачивания это # < . . ._start и # < . . ._End